# Converting a Class to a Class Library and Instantiating

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a class that I had written a long time ago in VB.net.  I want to use the class in C#, so to save time I thought I would just convert it to a class library.  I'm running into some confusion in doing this though.  When I instantiate my original class, I would use the System.Drawing.Save() method to save an image file.  See below `imageConv.Save(filePath)`.

```vb
Imports System.Drawing
...
...
''' <summary>
'''     Convert the image to a smaller more manageable 4-bit png
''' </summary>
Private Shared Function ConvertImage(filepath As String) As String
    Using image As New Bitmap(filepath)
        'Do Stuff
        'Convert it to 4BPP
        Using imageConv = BitmapEncoder.Convert(image, 4)
            'Update the filepath for saving
            filepath = Path.GetTempPath & "image.png"
            'Save to disk
            imageConv.Save(filepath)
        End Using
    End Using
    ConvertImage = filepath
End Function
```

Now when I copied the class into a class library project, added the reference in my C# project, and instantiated the class, I can no longer use the Save method.

```
    private static void compressBitmap(ImageData imgData)
    {
        using (Bitmap imageRaw = new Bitmap(imgData.bmpFilePath))
        { 
            using (ConvertBitmap imageCompressed = new ConvertBitmap())
            {
                imageCompressed.Convert(imageRaw, 4);
                //imageCompressed.Save(imgData.bmpFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?  I know I need to instantiate `ConvertBitmap imageCompressed = new ConvertBitmap.Convert(imageRaw, 4))` but it says 'Convert' does not exist in the type 'ConvertBitmap'.  It definitely does.  It's a public function.

```vb
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles
''' <summary>
'''     Copies a bitmap into a 1bpp/4bpp/8bpp bitmap of the same dimensions, fast
''' </summary>
Public Class ConvertBitmap : Implements IDisposable
    ' Flag: Has Dispose already been called?
    Dim disposed As Boolean = False
    ' Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    Dim handle As SafeHandle = New SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, True)

''' <summary>
''' Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
''' </summary>
Public Sub Dispose() _
          Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
    GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="disposing"></param>
Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If disposed Then Return

    If disposing Then
        handle.Dispose()
        ' Free any other managed objects here.
        '
    End If

    disposed = True
End Sub

''' <param name="b">original bitmap</param>
''' <param name="bpp">1 or 8, target bpp</param>
''' <returns>a 1bpp copy of the bitmap</returns>
Public Function Convert(b As Bitmap, bpp As Integer) As Bitmap
    Select Case bpp
        Case 1
        Case 4
        Case 8
        Case Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("bpp must be 1, 4 or 8")
    End Select

    ' Plan: built into Windows GDI is the ability to convert
    ' bitmaps from one format to another. Most of the time, this
    ' job is actually done by the graphics hardware accelerator card
    ' and so is extremely fast. The rest of the time, the job is done by
    ' very fast native code.
    ' We will call into this GDI functionality from C#. Our plan:
    ' (1) Convert our Bitmap into a GDI hbitmap (ie. copy unmanaged->managed)
    ' (2) Create a GDI monochrome hbitmap
    ' (3) Use GDI "BitBlt" function to copy from hbitmap into monochrome (as above)
    ' (4) Convert the monochrone hbitmap into a Bitmap (ie. copy unmanaged->managed)

    Dim w As Integer = b.Width, h As Integer = b.Height
    Dim hbm As IntPtr = b.GetHbitmap()
    ' this is step (1)
    '
    ' Step (2): create the monochrome bitmap.
    ' "BITMAPINFO" is an interop-struct which we define below.
    ' In GDI terms, it's a BITMAPHEADERINFO followed by an array of two RGBQUADs
    Dim bmi As New Bitmapinfo()
    bmi.biSize = 40
    ' the size of the BITMAPHEADERINFO struct
    bmi.biWidth = w
    bmi.biHeight = h
    bmi.biPlanes = 1
    ' "planes" are confusing. We always use just 1. Read MSDN for more info.
    bmi.biBitCount = CShort(bpp)
    ' ie. 1bpp or 8bpp
    bmi.biCompression = _biRgb
    ' ie. the pixels in our RGBQUAD table are stored as RGBs, not palette indexes
    bmi.biSizeImage = CUInt((((w + 7) And &HFFFFFFF8) * h / 8))
    bmi.biXPelsPerMeter = 1000000
    ' not really important
    bmi.biYPelsPerMeter = 1000000
    ' not really important
    ' Now for the colour table.
    Dim ncols As UInteger = CUInt(1) << bpp
    ' 2 colours for 1bpp; 256 colours for 8bpp
    bmi.biClrUsed = ncols
    bmi.biClrImportant = ncols
    bmi.cols = New UInteger(255) {}
    ' The structure always has fixed size 256, even if we end up using fewer colours
    If bpp = 1 Then
        bmi.cols(0) = Makergb(0, 0, 0)
        bmi.cols(1) = Makergb(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf bpp = 4 Then
        bmi.biClrUsed = 16
        bmi.biClrImportant = 16
        Dim colv1 = New Integer(15) {8, 24, 38, 56, 72, 88, 104, 120, 136, 152, 168, 184, 210, 216, 232, 248}

        For i = 0 To 15
            bmi.cols(i) = Makergb(colv1(i), colv1(i), colv1(i))
        Next
    ElseIf bpp = 8 Then
        For i = 0 To ncols - 1
            bmi.cols(i) = Makergb(i, i, i)
        Next
    End If
    ' For 8bpp we've created an palette with just greyscale colours.
    ' You can set up any palette you want here. Here are some possibilities:
    ' greyscale: for (int i=0; i<256; i++) bmi.cols[i]=MAKERGB(i,i,i);
    ' rainbow: bmi.biClrUsed=216; bmi.biClrImportant=216; int[] colv=new int[6]{0,51,102,153,204,255};
    '          for (int i=0; i<216; i++) bmi.cols[i]=MAKERGB(colv[i/36],colv[(i/6)%6],colv[i%6]);
    ' optimal: a difficult topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization
    '
    ' Now create the indexed bitmap "hbm0"
    Dim bits0 As IntPtr
    ' not used for our purposes. It returns a pointer to the raw bits that make up the bitmap.
    Dim hbm0 As IntPtr = CreateDIBSection(IntPtr.Zero, bmi, _dibRgbColors, bits0, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
    '
    ' Step (3): use GDI's BitBlt function to copy from original hbitmap into monocrhome bitmap
    ' GDI programming is kind of confusing... nb. The GDI equivalent of "Graphics" is called a "DC".
    Dim sdc As IntPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)
    ' First we obtain the DC for the screen
    ' Next, create a DC for the original hbitmap
    Dim hdc As IntPtr = CreateCompatibleDC(sdc)
    SelectObject(hdc, hbm)
    ' and create a DC for the monochrome hbitmap
    Dim hdc0 As IntPtr = CreateCompatibleDC(sdc)
    SelectObject(hdc0, hbm0)
    ' Now we can do the BitBlt:
    BitBlt(hdc0, 0, 0, w, h, hdc,
           0, 0, _srccopy)
    ' Step (4): convert this monochrome hbitmap back into a Bitmap:
    Dim b0 As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(hbm0)
    '
    ' Finally some cleanup.
    DeleteDC(hdc)
    DeleteDC(hdc0)
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, sdc)
    DeleteObject(hbm)
    DeleteObject(hbm0)
    '
    Return b0
End Function

Private Shared _srccopy As Integer = &HCC0020
Private Shared _biRgb As UInteger = 0
Private Shared _dibRgbColors As UInteger = 0

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
Private Shared Function DeleteObject(hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function GetDC(hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
Private Shared Function CreateCompatibleDC(hdc As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function ReleaseDC(hwnd As IntPtr, hdc As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
Private Shared Function DeleteDC(hdc As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
Private Shared Function SelectObject(hdc As IntPtr, hgdiobj As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
Private Shared Function BitBlt(hdcDst As IntPtr, xDst As Integer, yDst As Integer, w As Integer, h As Integer,
                               hdcSrc As IntPtr,
                               xSrc As Integer, ySrc As Integer, rop As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
Private Shared Function CreateDIBSection(hdc As IntPtr, ByRef bmi As Bitmapinfo, usage As UInteger,
                                         ByRef bits As IntPtr, hSection As IntPtr, dwOffset As UInteger) As IntPtr
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Private Structure Bitmapinfo
    Public biSize As UInteger
    Public biWidth As Integer, biHeight As Integer
    Public biPlanes As Short, biBitCount As Short
    Public biCompression As UInteger, biSizeImage As UInteger
    Public biXPelsPerMeter As Integer, biYPelsPerMeter As Integer
    Public biClrUsed As UInteger, biClrImportant As UInteger
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=256)> Public cols As UInteger()
End Structure

Private Shared Function Makergb(r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer) As UInteger
    Return CUInt((b And 255)) Or CUInt(((r And 255) << 8)) Or CUInt(((g And 255) << 16))
End Function

Public Sub New()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You should post the signature of the `Convert` and also `ConvertBitmap` class. Other wise its just guess work for the person answering the question.

Comment: @CoderofCode good call - updated.

Comment: There is no `System.Drawing.Save` method.  Presumably you are talking about the `Save` method of the `System.Drawing.Image` class.

Comment: You don't convert a class to a class library.  They are two completely different things.  That's like converting water to a glass of water.  Nonsensical.  You create class library project and then you add a class to that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the convert function returns a bitmap.  System.Drawing.Image.Save().  Yes, you're right.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I did create a class library project.  I created the class library project, then copied the class in and made the necessary changes to be able to use `using` directives with it.

Comment: Are you facing issues with the `save` method (which makes sense) or with the `convert` method? You have mentioned both and I'm confused.

Comment: @Taleeb the save method.  The function should return a bitmap object, so I should be able to call .Save() on it.

Comment: Try: `var myImage = imageCompressed.Convert(imageRaw, 4);
                myImage.Save(imgData.bmpFilePath);`

Comment: The commented line in the code above is: `imageCompressed.Save(imgData.bmpFilePath)`. `imageCompressed` is of type `ConvertBitmap`, which does not have a `Save` method. You need to save the object returned by the `Convert` method.

Comment: OT: `ConvertBitmap` is a bad name for a class.  Type names should be noun-based while method names should be verb-based.  `ConvertBitmap` is verb-based and would be appropriate for a method that converted a `Bitmap`.  Your class should be named `BitmapConverter`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'll take that into consideration from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get this error message:

> 'Convert' does not exist in the type 'ConvertBitmap'.

is that this line of code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
ConvertBitmap imageCompressed = new ConvertBitmap.Convert(imageRaw, 4))
```

That code is looking for a type named `Convert` (NOT a method) declared inside the `ConvertBitmap` class that has a constructor that that takes a `Bitmap` and an `int` as parameters.  Obviously there is no such type.

What you actually need to do is create a `ConvertBitmap` object, call its `Convert` method to get a `Bitmap` object, then call `Save` on that:

```
private static void compressBitmap(ImageData imgData)
{
    using (Bitmap imageRaw = new Bitmap(imgData.bmpFilePath))
    { 
        using (ConvertBitmap imageCompressed = new ConvertBitmap())
        {
            imageCompressed.Convert(imageRaw, 4).Save(imgData.bmpFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what I missed there.  Damn it!  Thanks!